“show databases” cannot find db, but when creating db it prompts: "xxx" db already exists
The 3meta+3tskv cluster I deployed repeatedly created a db with the same name. And
"show databases" cannot find db, but when creating db it prompts: "xxx" db already exists.
the log as follow:
public ❯ show databases;
+------------------------+
| database_name          |
+------------------------+
| concurrency            |
| container_kill         |
| container_kill_meta    |
| corrupted_packet       |
| corrupted_packet_meta  |
| disk_full              |
| duplicated_packet      |
| duplicated_packet_meta |
| io_error               |
| io_latency             |
| network_half_loss      |
| network_half_loss_meta |
| network_latency        |
| network_latency_meta   |
| network_loss           |
| network_loss_meta      |
| public                 |
| stress_1               |
| stress_2               |
| usage_schema           |
| write_moving_vnode     |
+------------------------+
Query took 0.002 seconds.
public ❯ create database write_alter;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030018","error_message":"Database \"write_alter\" already exists"}

The version of cnosdb I use is:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 6b3d820b336c6f83d1cc2f237ba206f0e1fee47b
Has anyone encountered this problem?
